# Sublime - Is there a shortcut to insert content between tags?

Tags: tags, sublimetext3

In Sublime3 Text Editor, I'm trying to type the following:

```
p some dummy text
```

and have the result be

```
<p>some dummy text</p>
```

I can't seem to find the shortcut for this.  Anyone else run into this? 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Emmet? If so, put the text between `{}`.

```
p>{some dummy text}
```

For more info, visit [Emmet’s Documentation](https://docs.emmet.io).